# Could a faulty SIM card cause my android to spontaneously reboot

Tags: reboot, sim-card

My android (Sony Xperia 10a) spontaneously reboots on a 1m to 15m cycle.   I had a Nokia before and I think it rebooted more often than expected as well.  My Google contacts, a SIM and AT&T are the only things I brought forward from one to the other so I suspect all three.

Does anyone know if a bad SIM can cause rebooting?

Comment: this question is too vague to be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I have had a windows 8 phone crash and switch off with extreme frequency- got new sim card issued by supplier and phone now totally reliable. it's the simplest thing to check and it doesn't require you to do the whole backup and restore thing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it could but not in this case.  I'm going to go with faulty hardware and here's why.  I have tried the following:

Action.... Rationale

- full reset ... installed too many
  apps and corrupted OS?
- full reset and
  reformat memory card ... corrupt file
  system on mem card?
- full reset and
  don't use a memory card ... defective
  mem card? new sim card ... bad sim?
- full reset + new google account ...
  bad data in google account?
- full
  reset + original google account but
  do not activate any location
  awareness ... suspect GPS issue

In each case I can get the phone to fail in 5-45 minutes and usually within 20m as long as I'm tranferring some data via 3g (youtube, downloads etc).

So, since I have swapped out everything except the physical phone hardware the problem must lay in the device itself.  Glad there's a manufacturer's warranty

Comment: I suppose my card finally caused the phone hardware to fail. it was restarting from time to time, but I ignored it. then it failed completely (restarting all the time when it has any energy, can't even boot into recovery mode). I thought it's the phone fault, so I put the card into another device... and this second device also started to restart. what's interesting, it keep have problems a couple of hours after I pull this problematic SIM out.

Answer (score 1):

Had these symptoms on a Samsung S3 Neo, pretty sure its the card because it does the same in my older phone but only when using 3/4G.
Interestingly it only happens when the battery is below 80% for some reason.

Also had the same problem on older non-smart phones, the guy at the shop asked "what had I done to it" because it refused point blank to even see the card at all.
Best guess is ESD but yet the card worked fine in the same phone for years without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it happned to me on my Samsung galaxy 6, i change sim card and it's work again

Answer (score 0):

I have an LG G4 that suddenly refused to turn on. I used my insurance and got a new unit sent out, swapped out my battery and SIM, and had the same thing start happening with the new unit. The tech at Verizon said it might be a battery issue, so I went and spent $43 on a new battery. No go. Still the same issue, plus the battery wouldn't charge, even when the phone was off.

At this point, the only original part on my phone is the SIM, so back to Verizon I go tonight see if they can/will replace the SIM.

Comment: how have that ended?